# How to display from another layout on Android Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a list of food pizza, burger, and drinks. Once, I click one of the lists on my listview I want to display the food name, description, and price to another layout. Can somebody help me with my problem? This is all the codes. I search a lot but I get the error and it is not working well. In the itemsDetails.java you will see the getter and setter. I have not done creating new .xml and activity

```
ItemsDetails.java

public class ItemDetails {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getItemDescription() {
        return itemDescription;
    }
    public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription) {
        this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getImageNumber() {
        return imageNumber;
    }
    public void setImageNumber(int imageNumber) {
        this.imageNumber = imageNumber;
    }

    private String name ;
    private String itemDescription;
    private String price;
    private int imageNumber;


}

ItemListBaseAdapter.java

public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

    private Integer[] imgid = {
            R.drawable.p1,
            R.drawable.bb2,
            R.drawable.p2,
            R.drawable.bb5,
            R.drawable.bb6,
            R.drawable.d1
            };

    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

    public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemDetails> results) {
        itemDetailsrrayList = results;
        l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
            holder.txt_itemPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());
        holder.txt_itemPrice.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);
//      imageLoader.DisplayImage("http://192.168.1.28:8082/ANDROID/images/BEVE.jpeg", holder.itemImage);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_itemName;
        TextView txt_itemDescription;
        TextView txt_itemPrice;
        ImageView itemImage;
    }
}

ListViewImagesActivity.java

 public class ListViewImagesActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
           @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ItemDetails obj_itemDetails = (ItemDetails)o;
                Toast.makeText(ListViewImagesActivity.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }  
        });
    }

    private ArrayList<ItemDetails> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();

        ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Pizza");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Spicy Chiken Pizza");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 310.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Burger");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Beef Burger");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 350.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Pizza");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Chiken Pizza");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 250.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(3);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Burger");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Chicken Burger");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 350.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Burger");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Fish Burger");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 310.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(5);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName("Mango");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Mango Juice");
        item_details.setPrice("RS 250.00");
        item_details.setImageNumber(6);
        results.add(item_details);


        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse? Why are you using ListView?

Comment: The IDE you are using is totally **irrelevant**.